# Why is Pandoc not converting a .tex to .pdf but will convert the .md fine?

Tags: windows, markdown, pandoc

I have a number of Markdown files which I am converting to PDF using Pandoc - including folding in some header files with LaTeX options.

This works if I create the PDF in a single step (MD → PDF), however, I need to perform some additional steps on the intermediate LaTeX file so I am trying to split the Pandoc process into two steps (MD → TEX → PDF) - which produces an "Undefined Control Sequence" error.

I have compared the `.tex` file produced by one-step-Pandoc with the two-step version and they are identical - including the relevant `\usepackage` commands for the LaTeX packages that produce the error.

I am running on Windows, and have updated Pandoc to 2.7.3 and updated all my MiKTeX packages this morning.

Minimal test files that produce this error:

`test.md`:

```
% Title
% Author
% Date

Body text
```

title.tex

```
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}\fontsize{11pt}{11pt}\selectfont
\sectionfont{
    \setmainfont{Arial}
    \fontsize{32pt}{32pt}
    \selectfont
}
```

When I use a single step command, the PDF produces correctly without issue:

```
> pandoc test.md options.yaml -o test.pdf -f markdown+smart+tex_math_dollars -s -V block-headings -H fontoptions.tex -B title.tex -B title_logo.tex -B header.tex --pdf-engine=lualatex
lualatex: warning: running with administrator privileges
lualatex: warning: running with administrator privileges
lualatex: warning: running with administrator privileges
```

When run in two steps:

```
> pandoc test.md options.yaml -o test.tex -f markdown+smart+tex_math_dollars -s -V block-headings -H fontoptions.tex -B title.tex -B title_logo.tex -B header.tex

> pandoc test.tex -o test.pdf -f latex --pdf-engine=lualatex
lualatex: warning: running with administrator privileges
lualatex: warning: running with administrator privileges
lualatex: warning: running with administrator privileges
Error producing PDF.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.81 \sectionfont
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second step should simply be:

```
> lualatex test.tex
```

By using pandoc to go from LaTeX to PDF you potentially lose information (because pandoc cannot represent all of TeX and more importantly, pandoc will use it's own [template](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates).)

Comment: Thanks - fixed the problem exactly.  :)